# Add ebay-api tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

It appears that there is no [ebay-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay-api) tag on SO and it would probably be a good idea to have it (we already have [paypal-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal-api) tag, so I see no reason for not having a tag for its sister API).

I don't have enough reputation, so I can't do this myself (hence this request).

Edit: As requested by ChrisF, [those questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22ebay%20api%22) would probably benefit from this tag. Incidentally, many of them are incorrectly tagged with the [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) tag (probably due to the lack of [ebay-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay-api)). I also noticed some questions incorrectly tagged with [paypal-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal-api) when they were in fact asking about things related to [ebay-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay-api) (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158506/how-to-get-paypal-transactionid-via-ebay-api)).

Comment: Are there any questions that would benefit from this tag? If so can you include links to them in the question.

Comment: @ChrisF I added those to the request.

Comment: @MarcinHabuszewski As you requested the tag can you also provide a tag wiki and excerpt on it?

Comment: For people that want to help, [here is a search link](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22ebay+api%22+-%5Bebay-api%5D+%5Bebay%5D+%5Bapi%5D) that should give you a shorter list of posts to edit.

Comment: @rene As for tag wiki, I'll see what I can do. However, I can't expert on this tag as I'm just a beginner when it comes to eBay API.

Comment: @MarcinHabuszewski If you read the [tag wiki guidelines](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/), use some google skills and an artist impression you can get that started. I've suggested myself a couple of tag wiki's before in area's I'm totally unfamiliar with...and they all got (robo-)accepted...

Comment: @MarcinHabuszewski take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) for inspiration...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK - I've gone ahead and created the [ebay-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebay-api) and added it to this question

> [Ebay API with description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002582/ebay-api-with-description)

You should now be able to edit it into the other questions in your search.

**NOTE:** Don't mass edit, do a few at a time over the next few days to avoid flooding the home page (how ever briefly).